# plt.scatter cannot recognize a cmap generated by ListedColormap()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to customize a Colormap with ListedColormap() for a scatter plot.

Here is a dataset for the scatter plot:

```
labels = [  0,   1,   1, 100, 100]
X = np.array([[0, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 2]])
```

This piece of code

```
color_list = ["red", "yellow", 'blue']
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=labels, cmap=cmap, s=200);
```

outputs

[image]

It seems that `plt.scatter` cannot recognize the `cmap` generated by `ListedColormap()`.

I constructed the `cmap` to have the points at the lower left hand corner to be yellow, which is not happening.

My understanding (0 -> red, 1 -> yellow, 100 -> blue) about the order of colors might be wrong.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Indeed it's [0, 33.33] -> red, [33.34, 66.66] -> yellow, [66.67, 100] -> blue. You will need to specify a `BoundaryNorm` to get the mapping you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon [@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)'s comment, for your current values of `labels`, you will get no yellow color if you consider the equally spaced range of 0-33.33, 33.34-66.66, 66.67-100. The following answer highlights this. The second figure below however shows the yellow color, provided you have the `labels` falling between the correct range. Check the [official page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) for more examples on `BoundaryNorm`.

The key line here is `ranges = np.linspace(labels.min(), labels.max(), len(color_list)+1)` which divides your range of values (`labels`) into equally spaced intervals.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = np.array([  0,   1,   1, 100, 100]) # converted to array for ease
X = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 0], [1, 0], [5, 0], [5, 2]])

color_list = ["red", "yellow", 'blue']
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)

ranges = np.linspace(labels.min(), labels.max(), len(color_list)+1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(ranges, cmap.N)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=labels, cmap=cmap, s=200, norm=norm)
```

[image]

**With yellow points**

```
labels = np.array([  0,   56,   63, 100, 100]) # <--- new label values
X = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 0], [1, 0], [5, 0], [5, 2]])

color_list = ["red", "yellow", 'blue']
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)

ranges = np.linspace(labels.min(), labels.max(), len(color_list)+1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(ranges, cmap.N)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=labels, cmap=cmap, s=200, norm=norm)
```

[image]