# How to have the cmap intelligently match a list for indicator purpose?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use a color map to indicate the label each data point belongs to in a dataset.

there are 3 examples and corresponding labels

```
X = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]])
labels = np.array([0,1,2])
```

in my design, labels [0,1,2] is represented by "crimson", "limegreen","navy" respectively.

```
color_list = ["crimson", "limegreen", "navy"]
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c = labels, cmap=cmap, s=100)
```

outputs

[image]

so far, everything is good.

when labels change, things go ugly

```
labels[2] = 1
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c = labels, cmap=cmap, s=100)
```

outputs

[image]

it is reasonable, because label 1 is the max one in labels and "navy" is the max one cmap.

but it is not what I need. in my design, label 1 is corresponding to "limegreen".

the ugly solution (snippet_1) shown below

```
color_list = color_list[:-1]
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c = labels, cmap=cmap, s=100)
```

outputs

[image]

the output is acceptable now with an ugly workaround.

the solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56632283/10253483) seems not apply here.

```
X = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[2,0]])
labels = np.array([0,1,1])
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
ranges = np.linspace(labels.min(), labels.max(), len(color_list)+1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(ranges, cmap.N)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=labels, cmap=cmap, s=100, norm=norm)
```

outputs

[image]

label 1 should be corresponding to "limegreen".

is there a way to make things elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BoundaryNorm` needs to take into account *all* possible labels. So it makes sense to start from the available colors and enumerate them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


X = [0,1,2]
labels = np.array([[0,1,2], [0,0,2], [1,1,1], [1,2,1]])

color_list = ["crimson", "limegreen", "navy"]
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(color_list)
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(len(color_list)+1)-.5, cmap.N)

for label in labels:
    sc = plt.scatter(X,[f"{label}"]*3, c = label, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, s=100)

plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=np.arange(len(color_list)))
plt.show()
```

[image]